# Does /ɛ/ have more than one sound?

Tags: differences, pronunciation, vowels, sounds, ipa

As a non-native speaker, I hear /ɛ/ as two different sounds depending on the word.
The first sound seems to occur in words such as *bet* and *get* and is closer to an /æ/ sound, while the second one sounds like an /e/ in words such as *employ* and "friend".

Is there a real sound difference for this symbol between these two cases, or is it my non-native ear that is tricking me?

Comment: *Friend* and *bet* have the same vowel /ɛ/.

Comment: It looks to me like you're noticing the nasalization of _employ_ and _friend_. English vowels before nasals are significantly nasalized, and this can result in a change in vowel phonation for some people.

Comment: As @John says, some speakers really do change their vowels before nasal consonants — this is the source of the *pin/pen* merger, which would make *friend* rhyme with *pinned* and *wind.* A milder version of this change would indeed turn the /ɛ/ in *friend* into something like an /e/. Native English speakers mentally correct for this change if they're from a region where speakers do it, but it would be likely to confuse ESL speakers.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul They can, but this is certainly not guaranteed in all accents and speakers. *Vide infra.*

Comment: I already knew it but I was talking about their standard pronunciations (GAmE, SSBrE) Excellent answer, btw. :)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer to the question of whether the English phoneme /ɛ/ “has
more than one sound” is simply yes, sometimes it can — but you aren’t
supposed to notice. :)

The IPA symbol you used, ɛ, represents the [open-mid (or *low-mid*) front
unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel).
It is typically heard in the English words you mentioned: *bet, get,
employ, friend*.  You can also hear it in the French word meaning queen,
*reine*, or in the Italian or Portuguese words meaning seventh,
respectively *settimo* and *sétimo*.

This is the sound which many native speakers use for what is known as the DRESS vowel under the [Wells Standard Lexical
Sets for
English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English).

But the thing is, that doesn’t mean that phonemic /ɛ/ is always going to
come out as exactly [ɛ] phonetically in all possible words irrespective
of the surrounding phonological environment, or in the accents of all possible
native speakers. It very much does *not* do that, although the whys and wherefores of
each situation are a little different from each other every time.

Dictionaries do not attempt to represent these nuances, and this can lead
people to think that everyone says that. They don’t. Every single person
has their own accent peculiar to them, and many regional accents differ
considerably from one another, including notably in how the DRESS vowel
works out there.

You haven’t said just which speakers you were hearing
with *bet* and *get* coming out closer to [æ] then to [ɛ],
but this is not at all uncommon. Any number of factors
can lead to it happening, but one commonly heard one
occurs in the chain shift known as the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English#Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift)
from the Inland North dialect of the United States. In a chain shift, a bunch of vowels rotate,
each moving out of the way of the other.  Because /æ/ moved under the well-documented
phenomenon of [/æ/ raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//%C3%A6/_raising),
phonemic /ɛ/ also had to move to compensate for this. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English#Backing_or_lowering_of_/%C9%9B/):

> ### Backing or lowering of /ɛ/
>
> The movement of /æ/ to [ɛə], in order to avoid overlap, presumably
> initiates the further movement of the original /ɛ/ vowel (the “short
> e” in DRESS) towards either [ɐ], the near-open central vowel, or
> almost [æ]. As the vowel [ɐ] is pronounced with the tongue farther
> back and lower in the mouth than in the sound [ɛ], this change is
> called “lowering and/or backing”.

However, what’s happening with your second pair, *employ* and *friend*,
is probably something else than what is happening with your first pair.  For one thing, these will
both be subject to what’s called [the *pin–pen*
merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Pin%E2%80%93pen_merger)
for those speakers who have that.

For example, [in Alabama the word
*ten*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/ten) can
come out [tʰɪ̠n], where ɪ̠ is a retracted version of the near-close
near-front unrounded vowel.  And in North Carolina it can come out
as  [tʰɪĭən], which all decoded out means:

```
 tʰ     voiceless alveolar plosive              U+0074   LATIN SMALL LETTER T
        aspirated                               U+02B0   MODIFIER LETTER SMALL H
 ɪ      near-close near-front unrounded vowel   U+026A   LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL I
 ĭ      close front unrounded vowel             U+0069   LATIN SMALL LETTER I
        extra-short                             U+0306   COMBINING BREVE
 ə      mid-central vowel                       U+0259   LATIN SMALL LETTER SCHWA
 n      voiced alveolar nasal                   U+006E   LATIN SMALL LETTER N
```

It’s not just in the American South that the DRESS vowel can shift around.
In several dialects of English from places as far away from each other as
Scotland and New Zealand, [the word
*seven*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/seven) ends up
having that “short i” vowel.

But you weren’t hearing the KIT vowel (normally ɪ) in *friend* instead of
the DRESS vowel (normally ɛ); you said you were hearing the FACE vowel
(normally e). There aren’t all that many accents where you can get a close-e instead
of an open-e there, but there are some.

For example, [in South Africa *head*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/head)
is [he̞ˑd̥], which decoded is:

```
 h      voiceless glottal fricative             U+0068   LATIN SMALL LETTER H
 e̞ˑ     close-mid front unrounded vowel         U+0065   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
        lowered                                 U+031E   COMBINING DOWN TACK BELOW
        half-long                               U+02D1   MODIFIER LETTER HALF TRIANGULAR COLON
 d̥      voiced alveolar plosive                 U+0064   LATIN SMALL LETTER D
        voiceless                               U+0325   COMBINING RING BELOW
```

And in North Carolina it’s [heɪ̆əd], which decodes to:

```
 h      voiceless glottal fricative             U+0068   LATIN SMALL LETTER H
 e      close-mid front unrounded vowel         U+0065   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
 ɪ̆      near-close near-front unrounded vowel   U+026A   LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL I
        extra-short                             U+0306   COMBINING BREVE
 ə      mid-central vowel                       U+0259   LATIN SMALL LETTER SCHWA
 d      voiced alveolar plosive                 U+0064   LATIN SMALL LETTER D
```

On the one hand, it’s not in theory too unusual that you’re hearing an [e]
in those words.  After all, it’s a sound that’s only a little ways removed
from [ɛ]. You can look at [e] and [ɛ] as tense and lax versions of the same
vowel, or if you prefer, as close and open versions, where [e] is tense or
close and [ɛ] is lax or open.

But I think what’s happening here in these two cases is that it’s the specific kinds of changes in the preceding vowel brought about by the nasal consonant in those words which is really what’s throwing you off. Well, not throwing you off, really. Just making it sound a little different.

Both words you mention have a nasal consonant immediately following the
vowel in question. Just as in Spanish, in English it is common but not
universal for a nasal consonant to change the vowel it follows a little
bit under regressive assimilation. It makes the vowel a bit nasalized, and
a little closer and tenser. But we don’t think of that as being a different
vowel, in part because English [and also Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology) don’t use the oral–nasal
distinction phonemically the way [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology) and [Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology) both do.

Your name is *Fabricio*, which I take to be either a Spanish name or a
Portuguese one, where it would be spelled *Fabrício* if we were being
orthographically correct.  This may well condition your perception of that
vowel, especially if you are a native speaker of Portuguese, because it
would make you hear any nasalization as a signal that it’s really a close
vowel being used there.

The Spanish word *tiempo* [ˈt̪jẽmpo] meaning time or weather does sometimes
have a nasal vowel there that’s a bit more open in some speakers yielding
[ɛ̃], but they don’t think about it because it’s not phonemic. And its
cognate in Portuguese, *tempo*, is nearly always a nasal close e with
[ˈtẽpu], although in Portugal it might occasionally come out a bit more
open, so more like [ˈt̪ɛ̃pu].

So my guess is that either the speakers you’re hearing say *friend* are nasalizing
and closing their open-e a little bit, or else you are a native speaker of Portuguese or Spanish who is therefore used to hearing a nasal e as a close vowel — or perhaps both.

Comment: +1 Nice job. I especially like the last clause in the first sentence --- "you aren't supposed to notice" sums up the phonemic principle perfectly.

Comment: Nice explanation and thanks for explaining the IPA symbols because I didn't know the advanced ones.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).