# Do Americans with PIN-PEN merger confuse "imminent" and "eminent"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels, mergers

The [PIN-PEN merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Pin%E2%80%93pen_merger) is a merger of the vowels /**ɪ**/ (KIT vowel) and /**ɛ**/ (DRESS vowel) before nasals [m n ŋ]. The resultant vowel is more raised and is closer to [ɪ]. *Pin pen, him hem, kin ken* are homophones for those who have this merger. Wikipedia says that this merger is commonly found in Southern American English, Midland region, in areas settled by migrants from Oklahoma and Texas who settled in the Western United States during the Dust Bowl and also AAVE.

I read a lot about this merger in different articles and websites and can't find any instance of merging *imminent* and *eminent*. I watched many Youtube videos (through Youglish), but of no use.

Imminent and eminent only differ in the initial vowel sound for most (if not all) speakers of General American and Southern Standard British English:

/ˈ**ɪ**m.ɪ.nənt/ and /ˈ**e**m.ɪ.nənt/

The vowels are before a nasal consonant, so PIN PEN merger is most likely to take place in the areas I mentioned above.

Do those Americans who have PIN PEN merger also merge *imminent* and *eminent*?

Comment: From the same link [Examples of homophones resulting from the merger include **p**in– **p**en, **k**in–ken and **h**im–hem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Pin%E2%80%93pen_merger) There's no mention of words beginning with the vowel sound, all the examples have a consonant in front of the vowel sound.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Congratulations on a well stated initial question; this is somewhat rare. While the vowel shift between *pin* and *pen* is regional pronunciation, the confusion of similar sounding words may be a different phenomenon. Many Americans would confuse *immigrate* and *emigrate* regardless of region. (The latter is somewhat rare in AmE.)

Comment: I asked one of my American friends who has this merger and they said they do merge *imminent* and *eminent*.

Comment: The two words are relatively rare in the US, and generally they can be distinguished by context, so it's unsurprising that people do not commonly make an effort to pronounce them distinctly.

Comment: Americans *with* the merger don't confuse any of these words. The only confusion is when talking to folks who don't.

Comment: I once worked with somebody who did not have the *pin-pen* merger but could not find *immense* in the dictionary to check the number of *m*s and the ending, because he was looking at the E section.

Comment: @PhilSweet: Of course they do. That's why they say *stick pin* and *ink pin* — so they don't confuse them.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the initial vowels in *imminent* and *eminent* are most likely to merge to [ɪ] in most of the accents having the 'pin-pen merger'.

It mostly occurs in words where the vowel and the nasal are tautosyllabic—in the same syllable.

Before nasals, vowels are usually [nasalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasalization)—the velum is lowered. The raised vowel probably results from the nasalisation of the vowel. [This paper by Raymond Hickey](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/developments-in-english/mergers-losses-and-the-spread-of-english/277257F011A2303B6AF30FC5D630F97B#) says that the vowel of *pen* /ɛ/ is raised due to the raising effect of the following nasal. (tchrist seems to have nailed it in [his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/545855/365490) to another question.)

According to [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455802?seq=1):

> "Before *m* and *n* in the same syllable, *e* and *i* are pronounced exactly
> alike, ***empty**, general*, etc. being ***impty**, gineral*. The same applies to /ɛ/ written *a* in *many*."
>
> [[Evolution of the Merger of /I/ and /ε/ before Nasals in Tennesse — Vivian R. Brown](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455802?seq=1)]

According to the paper above, [ˈɛ̃mp.ti] is realised [ˈɪ̃mp.ti] (or perhaps [ˈĩmp.ti]—with [i]) which accounts for *imminent/eminent*.

Note, however, that this merger only goes from /ɛ/ to /ɪ/, not the other way around.

The [Wikitionary page on 'imminent'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imminent#Usage_notes) gives a usage note, saying that *imminent* and *eminent* are weak rhymes. It further says that they become homophones in dialects with *pin-pen merger*.

[This website](http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/happy-tensing) (Self Gutenberg) also gives *eminent* and *imminent* as a homophonous pair in the dialects having *pin-pen merger*

And from [Understanding English Language Variation in U.S. Schools](https://books.google.com/books?id=4-nDBQAAQBAJ):

> The words *eminent* and *imminent*, which to most Southern English-speaking students sound the same, may also be similarly difficult.

Comment: I have pin/pen merger. I literally can't hear the difference. But I hear the difference between imminent and eminent.